# Como establecer una acl default sobre "other"

Tags: linux

pues eso quiero agregar a un directorio una acl de tipo default, pero solo la clausula "other", es posible ?

He probado con :

```
setfacl -m d:o::0 /directorio
```

Pero esto me crea las otras clausulas tambien, (entiendase : user y group)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estas viendo es que cuando seteas facl para other, user y group toman como default el permiso sin facl que tiene el directorio en ese momento:

sin facl:

```
# getfacl testdir
# file: testdir
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
# ls -ltra | grep testdir
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root    40 Apr 25 23:34 testdir
```

ahora despues de setear los permisos para other o vaciar de permisos:

```
# setfacl -m d:o::- testdir/
# getfacl testdir/
# file: testdir/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::---
```